# How to resolve unatural link from my site

Tags: seo

I have a business listing website which has links to business owners own business website..

Recently I've been getting requests to remove listing because they are getting warning from Google that links from my site to their site is unnatural link.

How do I go about change things on my site so I don't lose listing because Google are penalizing my out bounding links??

Comment: Well, if what you are doing is offering a "search engine optimization" service (SEO) as indicated by your question's tag, then Google are doing the right thing for their customers and for the internet at large by penalizing your outbound links.  When you look at it objectively, SEO is "gaming" the search engine algorithms to give an **undeserved** boost to site's search ranking.  That is not in the interest of internet users in general.  Search ranking should be based on what users want to see, not what businesses want them to see.

Comment: we actually have quality content, SEO is not our main thing. I can go as far as remove all the links pointing back to the businesses. just wonder what's the minimum needs to be done to satisfy google's requirement. for example, would set links as nofollow be enough? it was posted with SEO tag because this a question regarding SEO, not because SEO is what I do. obviously penalized by google is very bad for SEO

Comment: Discuss it with Google.  Because clearly their algorithms have classified you as an "SEO optimizer".

Answer (score 0):

The fast and quick solution is to make these links `nofollow`.